# Write proposal for logo design project

Tags: freelance-websites, attracting-clients

I've started to use a freelance website. I was able to handle the first four jobs that I received on the site, but I haven't been able to get jobs lately. Invitations keep coming in, but the potential clients aren't awarding their projects to me.

What do I offer a client in a Graphic Design project proposal?

Comment: Hello! Could you please edit your question to clarify exactly what's going on? As it stands, this is rather vague. It sounds like on a freelancer site, you've completed a few jobs, but are having trouble landing additional projects. You're asking, then, for suggestions for what else to offer to a client. Is that right?

Comment: I have edited and you are right. I am asking "what should I offer client in proposal".

Comment: What does your typical proposal look like? I still think the question is vague; I have no idea what you're currently doing to attract clients, so I don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: I'm with @ChrisForrence on this; I've attempted to answer the question (as I've seen this before and I *think* I understand what you're talking about), but more information on what clients are asking for in proposals, what competition is doing, and so on would be quite helpful.

Comment: You might check out what 99designs is doing.  They broker many design projects.

Comment: Hi @Murtaza, welcome to Freelancing.SE! I see that a few of your recent questions have been closed/deleted, and I want to offer you some support. Please feel free to ask in [chat] for tips on writing a good question, or even check on [meta] for the types of questions we allow. We want to help you with growing our community, and we're more than willing to help out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a proposal for a website, you should never just throw a mock-up out there.

When creating designs for a client, it's pretty important to work with them and find out what they need. Any client who simply takes a mockup offered from proposals is usually skipping the entire decision process and hoping that they can get a free (or at least cheap) design that they like from freelancers offering mockups.

Try and look for clients who are requesting graphic designers with portfolios. Provide live, previous examples of work you've done (with previous clients' permission), and build a portfolio to sell yourself to a client.

Any work you do should be paid for, in general; in some cases offering value to a client can be a good thing (and will possibly help them to reconsider you for their next piece of work), but when a client is fishing blindly for freelancers and saying something along the lines of *"Make me a design like x, and show me a mockup"*, and posting this on a bidding site, they are hoping that they can cut as many corners as possible.

If I were you, I'd stop sending a mockup in a bid and instead send a strong portfolio and a resume with references when bidding for these proposals. Act professional, and in your bid explain your experience and previous projects, and possibly how you handle the design process.

Comment: +1 for good point but not the answer of my question. I am not talking about worthless client who just bother freelancer, I am talking about a decent client. Mostly I discuss with client and before I am awarded, the client awarded project to someone and can't figure out what that freelancer has offered him. I am proving links to portfolio, attaching samples and etc.. but I don't get job. What you usually do to attract client and what you offer him to get job during discussion.

Comment: @Murtaza ah, I was trying to guess the context from your initial question

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you ask for feedback? Simply say,

> "Sorry to hear I didn't get the job, but I'm glad you found someone
>   who you're comfortable working with. To help me with my future
>   proposals, would you mind telling me where I went wrong?"

Asking this question will tell you everything you need to know.

Answer (score -1):

You should only provide a mock-up if you are asked anything, and the mock-up should be in the form of a low resolution picture.

Never provide a web-visible, HTMLized proper mock up. Its easy to just grab it from there and skin it into a template/website.

The picture you give should be low resolution, so that slicing it and skinning it into a website should not easy.

There are some who even try to grab the design from low res pictures, or copy the main elements in the design and evade paying.

Comment: Wrong!  @unity100, you are suggesting work "on spec".  If the OP is asked for any work product, including a mock-up, then the OP should be pressing the client for a signed contract before doing any work.

Comment: Which will mean he wont be able to get any jobs. As you see, he got 3-4 jobs, then he cant get anymore. which means that his reputation is not enough to get jobs solely on his past history. which means, there will be a lot of people rightfully asking him to provide some proof of his capability and his grasp of what client wants. only after he has some good number of jobs and feedback under his belt, he can get jobs on name alone.

Comment: I still disagree.  A GREAT portfolio can get work.

Comment: You need to be aware of what you are saying - "a great PORTFOLIO".

He has had FOUR Jobs. there is no portfolio.

Comment: Then he's got work to do :)

Comment: Exactly that. And in order to get jobs to show in portfolio - but MORE importantly FEEDBACK, he has to use any means possible to get jobs at the start - including manifesting mockups.

Comment: Simply because, even in quite respectable sites like elance - which verify almost every info you provide -, portfolio is still something under your control. So i uploaded 30 screenshots of websites there, with links to the websites. WHO can tell that they are mine ? you cant put a link under all of them. so presence or non presence of a link is not proof. therefore there is no way to prove that a portfolio is totally yours. What remains ? FEEDBACK. feedback in freelance sites trumps everything.

Comment: I think what @codenoire is referring to (and feel free to correct me if I'm wrong) is to _create_ work where there is none. That is, think of a project and execute it. Once it's finished, there's another project for the ol' portfolio (and I bet you can get permission from the "client" to use it in the portfolio)!

Comment: @unity100, I have 5 out of 5 star rated profile. All previous jobs were completed successful. I am proposing clients same as before but this time client isn't responding me.

Comment: 4-5 jobs are still not enough to receive projects without providing any guarantees and establishing trust up front, or get high budget projects. im speaking from experience. if your client is not responding to you, then it means either they were not satisfied with you or they found someone else.